# Sending mxd and qgs file - data in the same folder?

Tags: arcgis, qgis

I want to sent mxd and qgs file to someone.
Do the layers have to be in the same folder as the mxd and qgs file (unzipped) in order for the other person to be able to see the shapefiles when they open the projects?

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the case of mxd files (ArcGIS for Desktop) it depends if "Store relative pathnames to data sources" option is checked. You can find it in File --> Map Document Properties. 
If it's checked than ArcGIS for Desktop will search for layers relatively to the mxd file. If it's not, than it'll search for them in exact location you added them from.

You can find more info in [the ArcGIS documentation on referencing data in the map](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/referencing-data-in-the-map.htm), as well as [here](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/arcgis-relative-paths-in-mxds) or [here](http://gis.mtu.edu/?p=299).

I believe it's similar for qgs i.e. Quantum GIS.